# How to connect ubuntu server via SSH if networking is down

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I am facing weird in my new ubuntu server set up . Actually we bought new Ubuntu server which was working fine earlier and i can ping it as well as can access via SSH.

Now after running following command whole networking has gone down .
**sudo ifconfig eth0 down.**

now i can not access whole server via SSH neither i can ping it.

Can anybody how can i bring it back in earlier position so that i can access it .

Please note, server are on cloud so i can only access via SSH.If any other way to access it please let me know .

Thanks.

Comment: a security feature, how to prevent anyone from getting in.  it is normally done at the console.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the cloud instance, however way this is done with your provider. If in doubt, contact their suppport.

Comment: now the problem with provider is that we have contract for hardware support only . Any other support will not entertain by our provider . Any other way if i can manage it from my end.

Comment: If this is some cloud instance, there *will* be some way to shutdown/restart the instance and it most likely is documented somewhere. That's all we can possibly tell you. **READ THEIR DOCUMENTATION**

Comment: the _fastest way_ is to launch a new instance. but if data or config work needs to be saved then other image backups are needed. **READ THEIR DOCUMENTATION**

Comment: @Vish then you should accept the answer above by clicking the "tick" outline next to it, to put the question to bed.  Thanks!